# vim treat commented line as blank line

Tags: vim

I like moving through my code with the paragraph motions `{` and `}`. Is there some way to get vim to treat lines that are commented out (lines that contain **only** comment-colored text or whitespace, if that's easier) as blank lines? This way, I could move through commented out lines with the paragraph motion as I would blank lines.

c/c++ example (though ideally I'd like the solution to work with any syntax):

```
BLANK     ->  /* FOE DOC STRING
BLANK     ->   * ...
BLANK     ->   */
NOT-BLANK ->  int foe()
NOT-BLANK ->  {
NOT-BLANK ->      int x = foo();
NOT-BLANK ->      int y = fie(); /*
BLANK     ->      int z = bar();
NOT-BLANK ->      */ x *= y;
BLANK     ->  
NOT-BLANK ->      x = fee(x, fum(y));
NOT-BLANK ->      return x;
NOT-BLANK ->  }
BLANK     ->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jumping to the top or bottom of comments is done with `[/` or `]/` respectively. 
(Note: `[*` and `]*` work as well.)  The cursor can be placed either inside or outside of the comments.  So, at the top of C(++) files, I often hit ]/ to jump over the header comments.

If you want to get to the beginning of the `int(foe)` line in your example, I'd use the following mapping:

```
map ]/ ]/j0
```

This is far more efficient than use multiple paragraph jumps.